# simple radio button to select payments with SUM() issue

Tags: php, mysql, sql

This is my attempt in using radio button to execute query from MySQL database.  I am not sure if I am on the right track as I am still trying to test the code, but it giving me a blank page without even displaying the `first_payment`.

I am looking to create a simple code to make a list of radio button to display with `SUM()` at the output page.  I have a database created all I need is the option to select which payment to SUM up with SUM().

**HTML Code:**

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<form name="input" action="paycal.php" method="post">
<fieldset>
<legend>Which payment do you want to SUM up:</legend>
    <input type="radio" name="payment" value="first" /> First 
    <input type="radio" name="payment" value="second" /> Second
    <input type="radio" name="payment" value="third"  /> Third
    <input type="radio" name="payment" value="fourth"  /> Fourth

</fieldset>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />   
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**PHP Code:**

```
    // MySQL database connection, username, password, database name
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","xx","xx","xx");

    // Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$req=$_REQUEST['payment'];

// mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");

if ($req="first") $query="SELECT * FROM `Customer Information` SUM('$first_payment')";

$result=mysqli_query($query);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
echo $row['first_payment'];
}
mysqli_query($result);
mysqli_close();


?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Radio buttons must all have the same name to form a group.

Comment: Your SQL query is wrong. You must modify that.

Comment: You should never use mysql and mysqli together. The reason is because they are different API's and use different resources etc.. You should use [MYSQLI](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Answer (score 0):

You have mixed Mysql and mysqli. You have to use one method. I have fixed some of your coding error

```
<?php 
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","xx","xx","xx");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$req=$_REQUEST['first_payment'];

if ($req="first") {
    $query="SELECT * FROM `Customer Information` SUM('$first_payment')";
}

$result=mysqli_query($query);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
echo $row['first_payment'];
}
mysqli_query($result);
mysqli_close();


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

`Radio Buttons` Allow you to pick one value out of one group of values.

So if you want to have multiple values you would want to go with `check boxes`

If you are trying to enter the value of the radio buttons into a database you would need to change the `radio buttons` to this

```
<input type="radio" name="payment" value="first" /> First 
<input type="radio" name="payment" value="second" /> Second
<input type="radio" name="payment" value="third"  /> Third
<input type="radio" name="payment" value="fourth"  /> Fourth
```

Now when a user selects a value of the payment group it will post. You can then take that post and do something like

```
$payment = $_POST[payment];
```

Now that the `value` that was `POST` is a `variable` which is `$payment`

We can enter it to a `database`

```
/connect to MySQL
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "YourUserName";
$password = "YourPassword";
$sql = mysql_connect($servername,$username,$password);
mysql_connect($servername,$username,$password);

//select database
mysql_select_db("myDatabaseName");

//insert values
$insert_query = "INSERT INTO tableNameHere (nameInTableRow) VALUES (variablePayment)";
mysql_query($insert_query);

//close MySQL
mysql_close($sql);

?>
```

Comment: Thank you, but I am looking into selecting the payment option to display the SUM of whole column.